# Change order of jobs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

In my Jenkins dashboard I have four jobs.

```
job a
job b
job c 
job d
```

Is it possible to change the order in which these jobs are displayed?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jenkins, by default sorts jobs in ascending order.  1,2,3,A,b,c, etc.  However, you may be able to use this Dashboard Plugin to provide something closer to what you're looking for

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View

In addition, there is a plugin that sorts jobs in the queue based on priority.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin

I came across a JIRA issue for Jenkins which suggested sorting in descending order, but just moving around the order may be something you want to add to JIRA as an issue or look into creating a plugin for this purpose.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial

One simple thing to do would be to add a number to the beginning of the jobs' names to indicate where they should be in the list.

1 - Job 2
2 - Job 3
3 - Job 1

Comment: The numbering is ineffective when you have more than 10 jobs since 10 appears after 1

Comment: The problem with the leading numbers is you use the job name in other places like `build my_build_name` in a Jenkinsfile. So when you decide to change the order you have to rename the job in many places.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Delivery Pipeline plug in.  This will create a view that displays jobs in the order they are executed.  I am not sure whether it works if you have parallel jobs running, I haven't investigated too deeply though.

Second alternative is to add a leading number.  If you start with 1 and 2, you can then insert a 1.1 and everything will sort okay in the default view display.