# How to move Dashboard on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

How to move Dashboard on Jenkins. In way - tab a, tab c, tab b
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dhHY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only solution is to prefix your tab name with a number if you want to change the order :(

[Change order of jobs in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909274/change-order-of-jobs-in-jenkins)

Comment: That's exactly what I do. BTW in TeamCity you can change the order for    yourself and for everyone...

Comment: Thank You! Dashboards are ordered on name.

Answer (score 0):

You can select what tab a build job belongs to by editing the view
- Click on the Tab
- On the Left you will see option to "Edit View"
- Your list of jobs will appear there check the one's you want to show up on that view and save changes

Comment: I don't need to edit view in dashboard, I need to move dashboards.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the question unfortunately you cannot change the order of the view tabs right now since it is alphabetically ordered this is however a UI enhancement that has been requested in the past as stated above by @Bruno you can add a number in the start and that will change the order.