# Complete chronological list of all builds in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

This sounds like something like Google should answer but [I could not get it to](https://www.google.com/search?q=jenkins%20build%20history%20of%20all%20jobs):

I want to list all the builds ever invoked in all of Jenkins, ordered chronologically descending. Not just all the builds of a single job, which is available on the job page, but all of Jenkins. How do I do that? How do I know what the last 5 most recently invoked builds were? It is a very basic function but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

The `All` jobs tab, which lists all the jobs, could not be sorted.

Answer (score -2):

check out this plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View

related thread: [Change order of jobs in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909274/change-order-of-jobs-in-jenkins)